# How to get Ant build errors inside Eclipse "Problems" view

Tags: eclipse, ant, integration

When I set up an Ant script to run as an Ant builder in an Eclipse project, the only options I have for handling the output are to:

- show it in Console view
- capture it in a file

Is there any way to tell Eclipse how to parse the output and add entries to the Problems view accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are going to find a solution, but if you do it would have to be a third-party plugin implementing a replacement Ant Builder. As you've discovered, Eclipse Ant build integration doesn't support this.

You may also want to consider opening an enhancement request at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform site. While there is no guarantee that someone will step up to implement this feature, you never can tell.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case, but I hoped someone would find something I missed.